# Mark a single cell with a red dot (or red flag, or red cross, anything) when its value is over 95%?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

It's sort of a data validation, but I don't want to use data validation, I simply want to mark it.

I've dug through Conditional Formatting and didn't find how to do it.

Comment: When it's value is over 95% of what?

Comment: dig a little harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not convinced this way counts as programming, but Conditional Formatting can certainly manage what you want, *assuming the values are in the range 0-100% inclusive*, (and much of the rest of CF is covered here):

[image: SO48373566 example]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find the "no cell icon" option!